# Jasypt Maven plugin: "Unknown lifecycle phase"

Tags: java, maven, jasypt

As described in the [documentation](https://github.com/ulisesbocchio/jasypt-spring-boot#maven-plugin):

1. Add to pom.xml (and perform Maven reload)

   ```
   <plugin>
       <groupId>com.github.ulisesbocchio</groupId>
       <artifactId>jasypt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
       <version>3.0.3</version>
   </plugin>
   ```
2. To try it out, I run Maven with this plugin to get a single encrypted value:

   ```
   mvn jasypt:encrypt-value -Djasypt.encryptor.password="the password" -Djasypt.plugin.value="theValueYouWantToEncrypt"
   ```

But I get the following `[ERROR]`:

```
[ERROR] Unknown lifecycle phase ".encryptor.password=the password". You must specify a valid lifecycle phase or a goal in the format <plugin-prefix>:<goal> or <plugin-group-id>:<plugin-artifact-id>[:<plugin-version>]:<goal>
```

I presume the plugin installed correctly as even my IDE recognises it:
[image]

Any ideas?

Comment: I suspect that you had a space or similar in the command you used before `.encryptor`

Comment: Cannot reproduce using the given command.

Comment: @JFabianMeier I've copy+pasted it directly from the docs (actually multiple times from multiple sources) - I wish the culprit were a sneaky whitespace but alas

Comment: I would completely retype it by hand and see if the error persists.

Comment: @JFabianMeier I just did, I get the same thing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This command line worked for me.

```
mvn jasypt:encrypt-value "-Djasypt.encryptor.password=password" "-Djasypt.plugin.value=test"
```

The trace

```
[INFO] Active Profiles: Default
[INFO] Encrypting value test
[INFO] String Encryptor custom Bean not found with name 'jasyptStringEncryptor'. Initializing Default String Encryptor
[INFO] Encryptor config not found for property jasypt.encryptor.algorithm, using default value: PBEWITHHMACSHA512ANDAES_256
[INFO] Encryptor config not found for property jasypt.encryptor.key-obtention-iterations, using default value: 1000
[INFO] Encryptor config not found for property jasypt.encryptor.pool-size, using default value: 1
[INFO] Encryptor config not found for property jasypt.encryptor.provider-name, using default value: null
[INFO] Encryptor config not found for property jasypt.encryptor.provider-class-name, using default value: null
[INFO] Encryptor config not found for property jasypt.encryptor.salt-generator-classname, using default value: org.jasypt.salt.RandomSaltGenerator
[INFO] Encryptor config not found for property jasypt.encryptor.iv-generator-classname, using default value: org.jasypt.iv.RandomIvGenerator
[INFO] Encryptor config not found for property jasypt.encryptor.string-output-type, using default value: base64
[INFO]
ENC(5P+yq0XlMiew9438IxsILCXs/2nGH2C4eq3IYamXoDeVeYdzoJLhLZPBMpGC4kMA)
```

Comment: Perfect! For some reason it only works with the double-quotes on my version of Maven (3.8.1)

Comment: I have run this command mvn jasypt:encrypt-value "-Djasypt.encryptor.password=password" "-Djasypt.plugin.value=thimira"